# How can I increment a date by a few months?

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is my code that I have written:

```
create or replace procedure UPDATING_LOCATION(P_SHIPMENT_NUM IN NUMBER,
                                           P_SHIPMENT_DESTINATION IN VARCHAR2,
                                           P_ERROR OUT VARCHAR2) 
is
begin
  UPDATE  SHIPMENT S
  SET S.SHIPMENT_DESTINATION = P_SHIPMENT_DESTINATION
  WHERE S.SHIPMENT_NUM = P_SHIPMENT_NUM;
  
  IF SHIPMENT_NUM = '11'
    THEN
      TO_DATE('06-05-2020') + 1
      
      ELSE 
        P_MESSAGE := 'The shipment will be on time, which is ' || P_SHIPMENT_DATE;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  P_ERROR := 'UPDATE WAS FAILED FOR SHIPMENT' || P_SHIPMENT_NUM || '- SQL ERROR: '||SQLERRM;
end UPDATING_LOCATION;
```

Comment: You don't seem to be adding any months to anything. You are adding a day to a fixed date, which seems a bit pointless. (And you're relying on implicit conversions and session NLS settings, which is never a good idea). So it isn't clear what issue you are having, or what help you need. Please edit your question to add some explanation, with sample data and expected results. Also be aware that you may need to define, or at least understand, what happens around month end; is a month after 2021-03-31 supposed to be 2021-04-30 or 2021-05-01, or something else, for example?

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. You should take a few minuets to toke the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review the help action [ask]. They tell you the information you need to provide in order to get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: I don't see any variable SHIPMENT_NUM, as referenced in IF SHIPMENT_NUM = '11'  And if SHIPTMENT_NUM (wherever it is defined) is a NUMBER, you are comparing it to a character string.  Your use of TO_DATE is invalid, as you are not assigning the returned value to anything. You are assigning a value to P_MESSAGE, but you never declare/define P_MESSAGE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using P_SHIPMENT_DATE anywhere in your procedure's parameter list. I think that should be your OUT parameter in your procedure. -

```
create or replace procedure UPDATING_LOCATION(P_SHIPMENT_NUM         IN  NUMBER,
                                              P_SHIPMENT_DESTINATION IN  VARCHAR2,
                                              P_SHIPMENT_DATE        OUT DATE,
                                              P_ERROR                OUT VARCHAR2) 
is
begin
    UPDATE  SHIPMENT S
    SET     S.SHIPMENT_DESTINATION = P_SHIPMENT_DESTINATION
    WHERE   S.SHIPMENT_NUM = P_SHIPMENT_NUM;
  
    IF SHIPMENT_NUM = '11'
       THEN
           P_SHIPMENT_DATE := TO_DATE('06-05-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY') + 1;          -- You have to pick this date from somewhere.
           P_MESSAGE := 'The shipment will be delayed by 1 day.';
       ELSE 
           P_SHIPMENT_DATE := TO_DATE('06-05-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY');          -- You have to pick this date from somewhere.
           P_MESSAGE := 'The shipment will be on time, which is ' || TO_DATE('05-05-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY');
    END IF;  
EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
              P_ERROR := 'UPDATE WAS FAILED FOR SHIPMENT' || P_SHIPMENT_NUM || '- SQL ERROR: '||SQLERRM;
end UPDATING_LOCATION;
```